# 'Reflection' using structured-bindings

Tags: c++, c++20

I was wondering if it was possible to use fact that in

```
struct Foo
{
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    auto [a0] = foo; 
    auto [a1, b1] = foo;
    auto [a2, b2, c2] = foo;
    // auto [a, b, c, ...] = foo;
}
```

only the first structured-binding is valid, in order to create metafunction that takes any pod type and returns a tuple consisting of all the member types of the passed pod, e.g. for Foo it would return

```
std::tuple<int>
```

I tried something like this, but that didn't work out:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename U = void>
struct to_tuple;

template<typename T>
struct to_tuple<T, void_t<decltype([](T x) {
        auto [a] = x;
        return make_tuple(a);
    }(declval<T>()))>>
{
    using type = decltype([](T x) {
        auto [a] = x;
        return make_tuple(a);
    }(declval<T>()));
};

template<typename T>
struct to_tuple<T, void_t<decltype([](T x) {
        auto [a, b] = x;
        return make_tuple(a, b);
    }(declval<T>()))>>
{
    using type = decltype([](T x) {
        auto [a, b] = x;
        return make_tuple(a, b);
    }(declval<T>()));
};

template<typename T>
using to_tuple_t = typename to_tuple<T>::type;

struct Bar1
{
    int x;
};

struct Bar2
{
    int x;
    float y;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(is_same_v<to_tuple_t<Bar1>, tuple<int>>);
    static_assert(is_same_v<to_tuple_t<Bar2>, tuple<int, float>>);
}
```

Comment: Basically you want [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get).

Comment: [Find the number of structured bindings for any struct, not just aggregates. -- not-portable --](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/dz1sgk/find_the_number_of_structured_bindings_for_any).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue here is that a structured bindings declaration is just that -- a *declaration*. We cannot form a "structured binding expression" in order to get the type, which is required in metaprogramming to constrain a template (for e.g., the `void_t` pattern, or a `concept`/`requires` clause)

---

Per [[dcl.struct.bnd]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind), despite the presence of an *assignment-expression*, a structured binding is distinctly a **declaration**.

Template metaprogramming relies on *types*, and a declaration is without a type.
You cannot for example say `decltype(int a = 10)` or even `decltype(int a)` for this reason.

You *can* say `decltype(int{})` because now we have an *expression*.
For this reason, your `void_t` pattern does not work.

Unfortunately concepts/constraints don't help us, because we cannot have a declaration inside a requires clause (per [[gram.expr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/gram#nt:requirement-seq))

---

Personally I think it's a bit of an oversight that we cannot have the equivalent of `int{}` for structured bindings. But then again, reflection is on its way anyway, so the point is probably moot.

Edit: As [dfri pointed out](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/dz1sgk/find_the_number_of_structured_bindings_for_any/), there is a GNU extension called [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) that can make this possible (as an extension it is understandably not portable code)